# TPL sample on skynet benchmarks not really parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I found [this suite of benchmarks](https://github.com/atemerev/skynet) comparing parallel/distributed processing concepts across languages.

I looked at the code for the .NET TPL benchmark, found it a bit weird and went on to debug it.

[image: debugging threads]

It seems we have one task running parallel to the Main task and doing, if I understand it correctly, only an asynchronous reduce (aggregate) over all synchronous and recursive results.

Source code is [here](https://github.com/atemerev/skynet/blob/master/dotnet-full/Program.cs):

```
long limit = 1000000;
var x3 = Task.Run( () => skynetTpl( 0, limit, 10 ) );
```

...

```
static void skynetTplRecursion( ITargetBlock<long> src, long num, long size, long div )
{
    if( size == 1 )
    {
        src.SendAsync( num );
        return;
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < div; i++ )
    {
        var sub_num = num + i * ( size / div );
        skynetTplRecursion( src, sub_num, size / div, div );
    }
}

static async Task<long> skynetTpl( long num, long size, long div )
{
    BatchBlock<long> source = new BatchBlock<long>( 1024 );

    long sum = 0;
    ActionBlock<long[]> actAggregate = new ActionBlock<long[]>( vals => sum += vals.Sum(),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, SingleProducerConstrained = true } );

    source.LinkTo( actAggregate, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true } );

    skynetTplRecursion( source, num, size, div );
    source.Complete();

    await actAggregate.Completion;

    return sum;
}
```

Is my understanding correct? If not, why?

**UPDATE**:

The objective of the code as stated by the author of the repository:

> Creates an actor (goroutine, whatever), which spawns 10 new actors, each of them spawns 10 more actors, etc. until one million actors are created on the final level. Then, each of them returns back its ordinal number (from 0 to 999999), which are summed on the previous level and sent back upstream, until reaching the root actor. (The answer should be 499999500000).

Comment: why would you expect an async. aggregate to be parallel? Without further guarantees you cannot easily make this operation run in parallel (the map-phase is another matter) - in your case it would be possible (as `+` is of course assoziative) but the TPL has no way to see this from the delegate it is based on

Comment: I expected the code to be parallel because it's being compared to other parallel implementations in the benchmark suite. My understanding after looking at the source is as written in the question (not parallel). As I've never seen TPL, I decided to ask here if I my understanding of the code is correct.

Comment: you can make the sum run in parallel but the TPL has no way of knowing that - I guess the other implementations dealt with this in some other way - maybe I could help you further if you could show one of those running in parallel?

Comment: btw: I really only just had a real look on what's going on in detail and the way it's implemented (using the closure of the `sum` and mutating it is horrible ... this would most likely break with two threads acting on it anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the help understanding this, Carsten. There's a sample using async Tasks in the [same file](https://github.com/atemerev/skynet/blob/master/dotnet-full/Program.cs), and examples in other languages [on the repo](https://github.com/atemerev/skynet)

Comment: from what I see (the `skynetAggregator`) this version will aggregate on a single thread too (when all the other tasks finished)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not propagating results upstream like his proposal was.

Comment: aggregating on a single thread is the default frameworks can give you - if you have the special case of an associative operation you can do `(a*b) * (c*d)` instead of `((a*b)*c)*d` (and the obvious generalization) but if the operation is not associative (as many are) then this will obviously not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right. All the recursive code runs synchronously on a single thread. There is another computation that runs in parallel with that: summing the arrays in the `ActionBlock`.

This does not come close to the description of the code.

Comment: Not only there is no parallel computing in this program, there are no actors either.

Comment: @shay__ Dataflow blocks (at least some of them, like `ActionBlock`) are pretty close to actors. But there's certainly not one million of them here.